# C++ SDL2 memcpy texture color initialization

Tags: c++, colors, textures, sdl-2, memcpy

In [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698378/how-to-use-sdl-createtexture#26698600) we got this code to initialize a texture with some color:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *MainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        1024, 768,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
        );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(MainWindow, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_Texture *Tile = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 8, 8);

    // Initialize texture pixels to a red opaque RGBA value
    unsigned char* bytes = nullptr;
    int pitch = 0;
    SDL_LockTexture(Tile, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&bytes), &pitch);
    unsigned char rgba[4] = { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
            memcpy(&bytes[(y * 8 + x)*sizeof(rgba)], rgba, sizeof(rgba));
        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockTexture(Tile);

    SDL_Rect destination = { 320, 240, 8, 8 };
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Tile, NULL, &destination);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(3000);

    //Clean up
    SDL_DestroyTexture(Tile);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(MainWindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to initialize the texture with red, because `rgba` is initialized with `{255, 0, 0, 255}`. But I noticed that if I change this values, the result always shows some portion of red. Could someone explain this behavior? I guess I'm missing something in the `memcpy` line.

I would ask there, but I can't post comments.

Thanks! :)

EDIT: Here it is a capture with `{0, 0, 255, 255}`. With `{0, 255, 255, 255}` is all white, so it's like the red gets always added somehow.
[image]

Comment: Did you try it with blue and green? If you did, is the problem still there?

Comment: Could you upload a picture of your output please?

Comment: Example picture added.

Comment: I made the rectangles bigger and rendered 4 of them to test some variations. I checked and the result is the same with just one rectangle.